# Why is the title element taking up ALL the verticle space in the container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

Main title in the header is taking up ALL the vertical space and moving the `h2` out of the center to the right which is supposed to be under it and not connected besides for being in the same container.

https://codepen.io/ychalfari/pen/JVYoNW

https://codepen.io/ychalfari/pen/mgVdLr

These are a couple of the things I have tried but even just having the title in a `<p>` tag is taking up all the vertical space.

```
div class ="header-wrap">
    <header>
      <div class="span-wrap">
        <span id="my">My</span> 
        <span id="journey">Journey</span> 
        <span id="of">of </span>
        <span id="learning">Learning</span></div>
      <h2>Documenting the Learning Process in a Fun Interactive way! </h2>
    </header></div>
```

Here is the css

```
 header-wrap, header{

  display:flex;
  color:white;  
  background-color:red;
  height: 100vh;
  width:100vw;}

h2 {

  font-size:25px;
  letter-spacing:2px;
  font-family:'Raleway';
  align-self:flex-end;}

.span-wrap{

  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;}


#my{
  font-size:55px;
  position:relative;
  top:30px;
}
span{
  max-height: 65px;
  display:block;
}
#journey{
  top:80px;
  font-size:55px;
  position:relative;
}
#of{
   top:120px;
  font-size:45px;
  position:relative;
  margin: 0 35px;
  border: solid;
  padding: 1px 15px;
  max-height:60px;}
#learning {
   top:185px;
  font-size:55px;
  position:relative;  
}
```

What I expect is `<h2>Documenting the Learning Process in a Fun Interactive way! </h2>` to be centered at the bottom of the div unaffected by the "Journey of Learning" part.

Comment: You have `height: 100vh;` on the header (and the header wrap). This tells the browser to make those elements as tall as the viewport.

Comment: Children of a `display: flex` container will always take up the full height unless otherwise specified (like in your `<span>` elements, where you have `max-height`). If you don't want the two children of `<header>` to appear side-by-side, then `<header>` should not be `display: flex`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a *column flexbox* here by adding `flex-direction: column` to your `header`, and subsequently:

- add `flex: 1` to the `span-wrap` (occupies the available free space after *placing* the `h2` thereby pushing it to the bottom)
- change to `align-self: center` for `h2` element

See demo below:

```css
html body {
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

ul li {
  display: none;
}

header-wrap,
header {
  display: flex;
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  flex-direction:column; /* added */
}

h2 {
  font-size: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  align-self: center; /* changed */
}

.span-wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 1; /* added */
}

#my {
  font-size: 55px;
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
}

span {
  max-height: 65px;
  display: block;
}

#journey {
  top: 80px;
  font-size: 55px;
  position: relative;
}

#of {
  top: 120px;
  font-size: 45px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 35px;
  border: solid;
  padding: 1px 15px;
  max-height: 60px;
}

#learning {
  top: 185px;
  font-size: 55px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-wrap">
  <header>
    <div class="span-wrap">
      <span id="my">My</span> <span id="journey">Journey</span> <span id="of">of </span><span id="learning">Learning</span></div>
    <h2>Documenting the Learning Process in a Fun Interactive way! </h2>
  </header>
</div>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Arrays</li>
    <li>Objects</li>
    <li>Apps</li>
    <li>Design</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<section>
</section>
```

Comment: While this may work, I have to wonder what the purpose of is making `<header>` flex at all. It seems like you're setting `flex` only to go out of your way to strip that behavior. But please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: `flex-directon: column` gives us control over aligning a flex items vertically...

Comment: Correct. My question is: Why `display: flex` at all? Instead of adding three properties to make `flex` items stack vertically, wouldn't simply removing `flex` from `<header>` entirely achieve the same result?

Comment: yeah, I was focusing on the layout *with* flexbox since the question was using that :)

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks kukkuz :)

Comment: Obviously I don't know what I'm doing but I changed the ```<h2>```  to  ``` position:absolute;``` and it worked.
I'm just wondering WHY in the first place the element was taking up ALL the space? So I can understand the flow.

Comment: Now I'm starting from scratch just to see without flex what happens and I'm immediately stumpted by a random margin that wont go away at the top:
```  <header>
   <h1> My Journey<span> of </span>Learning</h1>
   <p>Documenting my learning of Web Dev in a FUN and interactive way!</p>
 </header> ```  
```
html body {
  margin:0;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
header {
  background:red;
  color:white;
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
}
```
Theres a space at the top of the page occupied by nothing although I set html body to margin:0;

Comment: by default *flex items* are arranged in a *row* - that's why the `h2` was to pushed to the *right*... now as you had `align-self: flex-end` it was pushed to the *bottom*

Comment: But why is the row taking up EVERYTHING not according to its height?

Shouldnt a row by logic occupy the horizontal space if anything?

Comment: see, arranged in a *row* means it comes horizontally and you've given `height: 100vh` to the `header` - another default for a *flexbox* is `align-items: stretch` (or `align-self: stretch` for that matter for the *flex items*) which means that each *flex item* will *stretch* the height of the *flexbox*...

Comment: maybe you'll have to *dig* a little bit more on how flexboxes work, hope you are following what I have said above :)

Comment: @YitzChalfari See my comment on your original question. A normal `display: flex` parent (without `column-direction`) will force all children to occupy the full height unless otherwise noted. Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/x3vmuzwn/1/

Comment: Ohhh I didn't know about the stretch being default either. Anyway I stopped using flex for this haha I'll get back to how make typography look how I want it to another time thanks a lot :)

Comment: I have upvoted but I haven't been on here enough for it count or something?
How do I close the question?